# A integral question about proof of Weierstrass Polynomial Approximation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I have a question regarding how to do integral. 
To prove Weierstrass Polynomial Approximation Theorem, A sequence of polynomial is defined as below.
[image]

It was said that  "The integrand in the latter integral is a polynomial of degree 2n in x with
coefficients which are continuous functions of t, and the integral is for each value
of n a polynomial in x of degree 2n (at most) with constant coefficients"

Can someone give me an idea of how to get this?  How to show it is a polynomial of degree (at most)2n?

Answer (score 1):

$$
[1-(t-x)^2]^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (t-x)^{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^{2k}\binom{2k}{i}(-1)^ix^{i}t^{2k-2i}
$$
Multiplying by $f(t)$ and integrating with respect to $t$, 
$$
\int_0^1f(t)[1-(t-x)^2]^ndt=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^{2k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{2k}{i}x^{i}\int_0^1(-1)^if(t)t^{2k-2i}dt
$$
This shows that $P_n$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $\le 2n$.

Comment: Thanks, It helped alot! Though there are two things I am not sure about. The first one is how did you deal with negative sign of x? (don't u need to have (-1)^k?) The second part is shouldn't last part of first equation have x^i*t^(2k-i)? how did you convert to x^2i and 2n-2i?

Comment: @yiG Oops, you're totally right on both counts. My apologies, it should be fixed now!